# leveling system python not working

Tags: python

```
if "comb" not in inventory:
            print ("You went over to the table and picked up the comb,")
            print ("it's been added to your inventory.")
            add_to_inventory("comb")
            print("")
            print ("Inventory: " + str(inventory))
            lvl = 1
            xp = 0
            lvlNext = 50

            xp= xp+10

            while xp >= lvlNext:
                lvl += 1
                xp = xp - lvlNext
                lvlNext = round(lvlNext * 1.5)

            print ('level', str(lvl))
            print ('Exp:', str(xp))
            print ('Next:', str(lvlNext))
```

When I run this in python, there isn't an error but it does not give me what I want. This is the result I receive:

level 1
Exp: 10
Next: 50

This is the result that I wanted:

level 1
Exp: 10
Next: 40

I am not sure where I made the error within my code.

Comment: You're never decrementing ``lvlNext``, so why do you expect it to be 40? (btw: you will never enter the ``while loop`` - at least not with those hard coded values).

Comment: It seems like you're asking "How do I make `str(lvlNext)` give me '40' instead of '50'?". Can't you just do `lvlNext = 40` if that's what you want?

Comment: It's supposed to turn into a 40 on its own, with this particular line of code: while xp >= lvlNext:
                lvl += 1
                xp = xp - lvlNext
                lvlNext = round(lvlNext * 1.5)

Comment: But the comparison for your while loop is xp >= lvlNext. xp is always 10 there and lvlNext is 50, so it'll never go into that code block

Comment: How could I fix that? So that it does run through the code with  lvl += 1 xp = xp - lvlNext lvlNext = round(lvlNext * 1.5)

Comment: I'm confused. Why would multiplying 50 by 1.5 and rounding give you 40? 50 * 1.5 is 75.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `do while` loop - do one thing, check if you need to do it again. While Python doesn't have a direct `do-while` you can create one:

```
while True:
#do something first

if condition_to_break: #check if we don't need to do it again if so break.
    break
```

This is useful for a leveling system where you can gain more xp than what you need to level. Take for example we gain 100 xp but only need 50 to level:

```
xp = 10
levelNext = 50
lvl = 1
while True:
    levelNext = levelNext - xp 
    if levelNext > 0: #meaning we didn't have enough to level 
        xp = 0
    else: # meaning we have more xp than we need to level
        xp = abs(levelNext) #take the remainding amount of xp and take the positive number for it
        lvl += 1
        levelNext = round((lvl+50) * 1.5) #gets the next tier of lvlNext since if we hit this then it means we've leveled up 
                                          #should use the current lvl to calculate the next tier of exp you need since levelNext is changing
    if xp <= 0: #this breaks out when we ran out of xp.
        break
```

Running the above code will yield you still level 1, with 0 xp left and 40 LevelNext. If you change the xp to 100 then you will be level 2, with 0 xp left, and 28 LevelNext points.

---

A side note, as it stands your level and exp and what not will reset every time you pick up a `comb`. if this is not the desired effect you might want to set your level outside of the `if` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Here the control is not entering the while loop at all. 
Just Change your while condition: 
while xp <= lvlnxt

Comment: This will just cause an infinite loop.